# How to debug python file separatly from other project if it has imports

Tags: python, python-import, fastapi, vscode-debugger

I am using FastAPI and have such project structure:

```
project_name
├── src
│   ├── main.py   # FastAPI entrypoint
│   └── package
│       ├── client.py     # some app logic
│       └── utils.py      # some helpful functions 
└── tests
```

I run the project using: `uvicorn src:main` and it works fine.
But sometimes I need to debug my `client.py`separate from the rest of the code.
Then I ran into an importing issue: `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

My import:

```
# in client.py
from .utils import some_func

# some logic
```

I tried different settings of my VS Code but nothing worked.

The one of my attempts to adjust debugger:

```
        {
            "name": "project_name - current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "/path/to/project_name/src",
            "program": "package/client.py",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
```

I'd like to find a way to set up the debugger so that I can debug the code separately. Or, if the problem is not in the debugger but in my code, then I would like to hear advice on how best to do imports or structure the code. Thank you